# Why does Lightroom reset the development settings every time I save the image in Photoshop?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop

For portrait retouching, I usually do basic calibration, color correction et c. in Lightroom. Then I proceed to Photoshop (*right-click* → *edit in Photoshop*) to do skin retouching and styling. Then I save the image (as TIFF with layers by default), at which point it gets automatically imported into Lightroom, where I do the final stylisation. However, if I go back to Photoshop to retouch the image any further at this point, once I overwrite the TIFF with Photoshop, Lightroom resets all the development settings for the TIFF (not for the original RAW file though). I can get my settings back by selecting the last entry in the development history or using snapshots I created earlier, but it's still a bit annoying. Why does Lightroom reset the development settings when I save over the image in Photoshop, and how can I circumvent it (I think it doesn't happen when I use PSDs instead of TIFFs, but that's only a workaround)

Comment: Is it saving a new copy of the Tiff, or over the top of the original?

Comment: @CrazyDino It's saving over the TIFF created when I first edited it it Photoshop. After all, I don't want to create a seperate version every time I go back to Photoshop to change a tiny detail

Comment: I'm wondering if that's the reason (and because of it being a TIFF rather than a PSD)

Comment: @CrazyDino Well I'm saving over the file, but the development settings are stored in the Lightroom database, they shouldn't be affected by it ... Photoshop also doesn't create xmp sidecars for the tiffs. Maybe the tiffs have embedded settings for Adobe Camera Raw, but that still seems curious

Comment: I'd expect the settings have been incorporated into the TIFF when you've gone to edit it (again), hence the reset. Where as a PSD you just edit, I wonder if you're effectively edit an export of the TIFF in Photoshop.

Comment: @CrazyDino No they haven't, the original files aren't touched by Lightroom at all

Comment: Oh wow. That's weird then. If you don't get an answer, maybe contact Adobe? Could be a bug that needs raising.

Comment: Yeah I might do that, but I don't think it's a bug. Rather a sideeffect of the intended functions and interaction between the two programs that I don't understand

Comment: If you used adjustment layers in PS, I'd try flattening the TIFF before saving to see if that older LR data is preserved, although I'm not sure where in the file the LR edit "lives".

Comment: @KnobScratcher The Lightroom development settings aren't stored in the file, but in Lightrooms database of the catalogue. This is why I find this curious

Comment: ...but PhotoShop isn't accessing the LR database when you're adjusting the (LR edited) image from LR to PS. What does LR send to the PS application the first  time that it doesn't see the second time?

Comment: @KnobScratcher Well the first time I'm sending the picture from Lightroom to Photoshop, it's a CR2 RAW with LR adjustments that get rasterized in Photoshop. Photoshop can't save over those as it's a proprietary format, so once I save the image from within Photoshop it creates a TIFF with layers which gets imported back into Lightroom, which I then finalize in Lightroom. If I go back to PS, Lightroom asks me whether I want to edit a copy or the original TIFF. As I don't want to create another copy, I select the latter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a LR bug (feature) in a recent LR or PS release. I work like this too (and with TIF files) - it's only recently I've noticed this behaviour (I've been using LR since v1 (and PS CS3) and while it has occasionally happened before it appears to occur more often, but not always, with the latest CC LR/PS).

Invalidating the develop settings would appear to be correct if the image dimensions have been modified (and I've definitely seen this behaviour), but otherwise it has worked as you expect for ... forever (until recently).

Answer (score 0):

When you select Edit in->Photoshop is there a dialog asking you what version to edit? I get a dialog asking whether to edit the original, a copy, or a copy with adjustments.

This Adobe help page has info:

https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/help/editing-photoshop-or-photoshop-elements.html

If you want your new Lightroom adjustments preserved, try selecting that option.

Comment: It does, as I mentioned in the comments, but that's not really a solution. I want to edit the TIFF within Photoshop, but still retain my Lightroom adjustments. After all, the development setting of Lightroom aren't included in the TIFF, so there's no reason they should be reset once I save over the image in Photoshop

Comment: You can't. The underlying file has changed and so the changes to it have no reference. The only way to do it is duplicate the file and then sync the edits to the new file.